# Как на stylus записать стили?

Tags: css, stylus

как на stylus записать max-width: min(100vw, 816px);

если прям так записать - не работает

Comment: да вроде работает я [тут](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=body%20%7B%0A%20%20font%3A%2014px%2F1.5%20Helvetica%2C%20arial%2C%20sans-serif%3B%0A%20%20%23logo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20border-radius%3A%205px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20max-width%3A%20min(100vw%2C%20200px)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) проверял или нужно сохранить min?

Answer (score 1):

Знаю два способа:

1. Передать именно CSS, при помощи [@css](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/literal.html)

   ```
   selector
     @css {
       max-width: min(100vw, 816px);
     }
   ```
2. Передать строкой, но "развернуть" через [unquote()](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#unquotestr--ident)

   ```
   selector
     max-width unquote('min(100vw, 816px)')
   ```